# Environ function doesn't support saving file dynamically in My Documents which is in D drive?

Tags: excel, directory, vba

I have some line of code that works best for my machine as I have "My Document" directory in C drive. Now that I have been given a new laptop in which my macro doesn't work because here directory in D drive. Below is my code:
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then

```
    If MsgBox("Do you want to save the Output to My Documents?", vbYesNo, "Successful!!") = vbYes Then

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Environ$("UserProfile") & "\Documents\" & _
        "Abandoned Projects - Bridge Request" & " - " & Format(Date, "(DD-MMM-YY)") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        MsgBox "Output is saved to " & "My Documents!", vbInformation, "Finishing..."
    End If

End If
```

I think the "Environ" function taking the default directory as C drive which is the problem. How can I make this work?

Please help, I am trying this since 2 days :(

Best,
Keyur Parekh

Comment: Try changing Documents to My Documents see if that works

Comment: Do you get an errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from WScript.Shell.SpecialFolders:

```
Dim docPath As String
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    docPath = .SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
End With

Debug.Print docPath
```